# Remove current event handler in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove an event handler when an event is triggered. I can't use `one()` because there are cases when I don't want to remove the event handler. Here's what I mean:

```
$('#a').on('click',function(){
  if(...)
    // remove current event handler
});
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that there are other event handlers attached to `$('#a')`. I only want to remove the current one.

Comment: try writing same question in google

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/), with name spaced [event names](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

```
$('#a').on('click.myevent', function () {
    if (...)
    // remove current event handler
    $(this).off('click.myevent')
});
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it is [namespaced event names](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) - used to make sure that we don't unbind other click event handler

Comment: This will remove all events with that namespace. Which means that 'myevent' must be unique identifier.

Answer (score 14):

To unbind an event handler within itself:

```
$("#a").on("click", function(evt){
    if (...)
    {
        $(this).off(evt);
    }
});
```

It isn't very well documented in [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/), but you can read a better explanation of this "third form" from section "Using the Event Object" in  [.unbind()](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Answer (score -1):

**Can you please try this:**

```
$('#a').on('click',function(){
  if(...)
   {

   $(this).unbind('click');  or $(this).off('click')
}    

});
```

**Bind and unbind are for backward compatibility. You should on/off to detach or attach event handlers**

hope this helps..

Comment: This will remove all `click` event handlers. OP only wants to remove a specific handler.